# (C++) Visual Studio 2019 - std::std::_Invoke_traits_nonzero has no 'type' member

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, visual-studio-2019

I have a struct `Foo` that accepts as template `T` a lambda function and as `...Qs` other `Foo`'s. Inside this `Foo` struct I define `R` as `using R = std::invoke_result_t<T, typename Qs::R...>`.

The entire code looks as follows:

```c++
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename ...Qs>
struct Foo
{
    using R = std::invoke_result_t<T, typename Qs::R...>;

    Foo(T t, Qs ...qs) {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto f1 = Foo([] { return 4; });
    auto f2 = Foo([] { return 6; }, f1);

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles if in main I just use the `f1` but when I add the second line (the `auto f2 = ...`) the compiler starts to complain with following errors:

```
error C2794: 'type': is not a member of any direct or indirect base class of 'std::_Invoke_traits_nonzero<void,T,int>'
with
[
    T=main::<lambda_4b41af0c8bf71ed9014846a5c48d3ef2>
]
message : see reference to alias template instantiation 'std::invoke_result_t<main::<lambda_4b41af0c8bf71ed9014846a5c48d3ef2>,int>' being compiled
message : see reference to class template instantiation 'Foo<main::<lambda_4b41af0c8bf71ed9014846a5c48d3ef2>,Foo<main::<lambda_31970e658595f43034db3e80ee15a00d>>>' being compiled
error C2938: 'std::invoke_result_t' : Failed to specialize alias template
```

I'm using Visual Studion 2019 with ISO C++ 17 (which was the only configuration that I've changed in the project). Does someone has any idea of what I did wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you wish

```
using R = std::invoke_result<T, typename Qs::R...>;
```

The `std::invoke_result_t` after expanding is

```
using R = std::invoke_result<T, typename Qs::R...>::type;
```

`Qs::R` is `invoke_result_t`, and `invoke_result_t` does not have the member `::type` (`std::invoke_result<T, typename Qs::R...>::type::type`)

Comment: Thank you very much. It did solve my problem